# Chrome extension authentication using existing site authentication

Tags: google-chrome-extension, forms-authentication

I'm developing a Chrome plug-in that needs to access a REST web service that is hosted on the same domain as my web site. The web service requires that the user be logged in. The website provides account registration and authentication. I would like to be able access the web service from the plugin without requiring the user to log in again from the plugin when they have already logged in to the website. I'm not sure how to do this. I'm using the forms authentication provided by ASP.NET MVC4 for the website. And the Chrome plugin, of course, is using JavaScript's XMLHttpRequest client-side to call the web service.

There are many plugins that do this. 'Delicious Bookmarks Extension' and 'Add to Amazon.com Wishlist' are a couple examples.

Comment: have you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do this the way I wanted.  Chrome won't, for good security reasons, send the cookies of one site to another site even if one of the "sites" is technically just a Chrome extension.

I ended up turning the parts of the plugin that required authentication into iframes that were served by the website that had been logged in to.  This allows Chrome to send the cookies when the iframe source is requested.  This is how the Delicious and Amazon.com plugins work. There is nearly no code being run in the extension it is mostly all provided by the page in the iframe.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you did this? My extension has an iframe in a popup window, but despite being logged in to the site from a chrome browser window with my credentials, opening the popup still doesn't work. I use javascript to inject the src of the iframe on DOMContentLoaded.